# Why generic Element behave different when defined as Double?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a simple class:

```
class DimensionTree<Element> {

    var spot:Element
    var nextDim: [DimensionTree<Element>]

    init(_ spot:Element, _ nextDim: [DimensionTree<Element>] = [] ) {
        self.spot = spot
        self.nextDim = nextDim
    }
}
```

And I try to add class function in extension:

```
extension DimensionTree {
    class func makeTreeFrom(_ spots:[[Element]], from level:Int = 0) -> [DimensionTree <Element>]{
        if spots.count > 0, spots[0].count > 0 {
            var trees :[DimensionTree<Element>] = []
            let axisSpots = Set(spots.map { $0[0] })
            // Here I got an error: "Type 'Element' has no subscript members"
            //... some code
            return trees
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

I got an error `"Type 'Element' has no subscript members"`. But if I assign Element == Double:

```
extension DimensionTree where Element == Double
```

extension compiles and works with no problem. Double has no `subscript members` too, Elelment is inside list of lists... Why it could not compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading. A `Set` can only be created from `Hashable`
elements. `Double` does conform to the `Hashable` protocol, that's why

```
extension DimensionTree where Element == Double { ... }
```

compiles. Generally, you can constrain the extension with

```
extension DimensionTree where Element: Hashable { ... }
```

to make it compile.

Comment: or `class func makeTreeFrom<Element: Hashable >(_ spots:[[Element]], from level:Int = 0) -> [DimensionTree <Element>]{`

Comment: @Sh_Khan: You are right, that would work as well because this is a class method. In an instance method it can be problematic because it defines a *new* placeholder type “Element.”